# How to learn math by self-teaching [Without books, or outside help]

Tags: self-learning

I'm thinking along the lines of attempting to explore mathematics by making my own discoveries as if it's the **new frontier**. As if I was a mathematician from 2000 B.C.

I know this sounds really strange but I'm curious - has anyone tried rediscovering mathematics? (who isn't an advanced mathematician) because I think it would be really fun.

If it matters - my most recent math classes were calc 2 and discrete structures.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to try to rediscover some of the math that has been developed through history? Or you are looking for tips on how to do original research in a particular way?

Comment: Rediscover math that has been developed through history.

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to do that? Simply don't read existing math...

Comment: Right. I guess I don't even know here to start, maybe number theory. I was also curious if other people had tried doing it and if it had worked for them. Maybe this question wasn't worth asking, but I figured I'd ask just to see

Comment: I mean rediscover a very small fraction of mathematics - just a small sector if anything. Thanks for the reply regardless

Comment: Okay. Try to prove this fact. If you take a point $P$ inside a triangle $ABC$, then the sum of the distances from $P$ to the sides $AB$, $BC$, $CA$ does not exceed half of the sum of the distances from $P$ to the three vertices $A$, $B$ and $C$ of the triangle.

Comment: Try to prove that there is no biggest prime number. It will probably take a while but give you some interesting insights

Comment: Gregor has given you a much easier problem than I suggested. That may be closer to what you want.

Comment: Thanks, for the help. I'll try Gregor's recommendation first.